# Avoiding downcasting when calling interface methods

Tags: java

Ok, Im having a stupid moment.

I want to be able to do something like this

```
class Example {
    public State currentState;
}

interface State{}

interface StateCallbacks
{
    public void onState(IdleState state);
    public void onState(ContactingState state);
    public void onState(SuccessState state);
    public void onState(FailedState state);
}
```

and be able to call `onState(exampleInstance.currentState))` and have the right method called.

Now Im aware why this cant be done, as there is no garentee that there would exist an `onState` method fir all infinite possible subclasses of `State`.

My question is whats a good way to achieve something like this without the `instanceOf` operator. For example i could just include an `onState(State)` method, but then the implementor would end up using `instanceOf`.

The idea is that a View object would implement the callback interface and put view-manipulation logic in depending on the state passed. Each state may have complex meta-data associated.

AFAIK it can be done with event buses that support event and/or subscriber inheritance, but only by the nature of how these things work and the EventBus doesnt care if there is no event handling method defined to handle a particular event, unlike our friend the compiler.

I know its a simple problem, but well the problem is, I too am simple.

Many thanks for any suggestions :)

Comment: what is the relationship between `State` and the various ...State classes?

Comment: They are all possible states the controller can be in

Comment: Those are not class relationships -- what are those?

Comment: Ah sorry, `IdleState` would `extend` or `implement` `State`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is typically solved by using the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

You implement it as follows:

```
interface State {
    void accept(StateCallbacks visitor);
}
```

and then in all `State.accept` implementations you do `visitor.onState(this)`, so for instance `IdleState` would look as follows:

```
public class IdleState implements State {
    ...
    void accept(StateCallbacks visitor) {
        visitor.onState(this);
    }
}
```

(Note that what you call `StateCallbacks` would in the visitor pattern typically be called a `StateVisitor`.)

You can then invoke the correct method with, say,

```
exampleInstance.currentState.accept(new StatePrinter());
```

if you want to do some custom printing of the current state.

Comment: +1 Many thanks. This looks very promising. I will look into this approach in the GoF book and return!

Comment: Yup - this is a revelation to me. I have come up against this sort of issue over the last few years a couple of times, this is a very elegant and powerful solution. Reading up on it the key to its success in this scenario is that it utilises `double-dispatch` as it "lets visitors request different operations on each class of element" (GoF). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to invert control and have onState be implemented by the subclass rather than the callbacks class.

Something like this:

```
class Example {
    public State currentState;
}

interface State{
  public void doOnState();
}

abstract class StateCallbacks
{
    public void onState(State state){
      state.doOnState();
    }
}
```

Comment: This presumes that each State implementation can do its own doOnState() logic.  I think the question is how to have this logic split out per state within the StateCallbacks class, though I'm not sure yet.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the OP can't create new `StateCallbacks` implementations easily.

Comment: Agreed.  It's unclear whether there will be arbitrarily many states, or whether the set of states will be known from the begininning.

Comment: The set of states will be known from the start. The problem with this approach however is that the state classes would need to contain all the view logic inside `doOnState()`, which is not ideal. Maybe I have misunderstood and this is not the case. The answer from @aioobe http://stackoverflow.com/a/26221817/236743 would not have this drawback, as any object could implement custom behaviour based upon the state objects type.